# User registration using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check if a username is already registered. If not, I want to register it and then give back the value of Role. Unfortunately it doesn't do that >_< well it works on login though...

Register codes:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","d_database");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $Role = $_POST['Role']
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Role FROM user where username='$username'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if(mysql_num_rows($row)==0){
        $qry = "INSERT INTO user(fname, lname, username, email, password, Role)
            value('fname', 'lname', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'Role'");
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Role FROM user where 
            username='$username'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $data = $row[0];
        echo $data;

    }else{
        echo"name already exists";

    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

my login codes

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","d_database");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Role FROM user where 
        username='$username' and password='$password'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $data = $row[0];
    if($data){
        echo $data;
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: well first off, you dont appear to be doing the insert.  $qry = "INSERT INTO user(fname, lname, username, email, password, Role)
            value('fname', 'lname', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'Role'");

Comment: Object-oriented programming? well i wanted to do that but well doing it this way makes me learn more....

Comment: Your code is **wide open** to injection, use parameterised queries instead and **don't** store passwords in plaintext.

Comment: View my answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003343/user-registration-using-php/28004453#28004453](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003343/user-registration-using-php/28004453#28004453) @george

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=d_database', 'root', 'password');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$Role = $_POST['Role'];

$roleStmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Role FROM user WHERE username = :username");
$roleStmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
if(!$roleStmt->execute()) {
    echo "Failed to execute role selection";
}

if($roleStmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    echo "name already exists";
} else {
    $userStmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, username, email, password, Role) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :username, :email, :password, :Role)");
    $userStmt->bindParam(':fname', $fname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $userStmt->bindParam(':lname', $lname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $userStmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $userStmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $userStmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $userStmt->bindParam(':Role', $Role, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if(!$userStmt->execute() OR $userStmt->rowCount() == 0) {
        print_r($userStmt->errorInfo());
        echo "could not create user";
    }  else {
        echo "User created <br/>";
        if($roleStmt->execute()) {
            $role = $roleStmt->fetch();
            echo "Users Role: ${role['Role']}";
        }
    }
}
```

As a tip, don't use unprepared statements like that. Your are injecting your php variables into sql statements, which is really dangerous.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Role FROM user where 
    username='$username' and password='$password'");
```

if someone would try to make you sad, he or she could enter

```
x'; DROP ALL TABLES; --
```

as their username or password and your database tables would be gone, so always prepare your parameters. I would advise you to read up on PDO http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases_interacting or to use a library. Then look at their implementation. It is really important to get stuff like registration and login kinda right.

Comment: Do this as a comment, it doesnt solve the problem he is encountering. *edit* I see you edited it as I was typing this and added a possible solution (better to add first solution, then handle tips).

Comment: SO wouldn't let me yet. I found it to be to problematic, too just ignore it. And I answered his question, through the static strings instead of $fname, $lname... thing. This is causing it to not write anything useful to the database. But I will try to do better next time :D *edit* now you edited too :D Sorry for the confusion, yeah, i forgot about the second part and it came back to me right after i clicked send

Comment: I agree, that his code is vunerable for injections, there is no doubt about it, yet the question was something completely different (as I agree, its a sql statement error where he doesnt use his variables,)

Comment: nothing to do with sql injection.  also you mentioned his query doesn't work because of such and such.  yet the query is never executed.

Comment: Yeah, that is a nice catch, didn't notice that in fact it is never executed. I just looked at the query itself which is wrong nevertheless. And that doesn't change the fact that the code in it's current state is really dangerous to put out there.

Comment: so.. what should i do XD

Comment: at least change the 'lname' to $lname and so forth. and you need to execute it with mysqli_query($con, $qry); or nothing will happen. If it really is only available to you, you wouldn't have to worry too much. But read that stuff up, when ever you feel like it, it is really important.

Comment: change it to

$qry = "INSERT INTO user(fname, lname, username, email, password, Role)
    values($fname, $lname, $username, $email, $password, $Role");
still shows the name already exists

Comment: well, have you checked the database to see if it already exists? Btw, your $data would have to be $row[0]['Role'] to show you the role, but that's in a next step. Just wanted to point out. And that's by using mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array

Comment: yeah... but it didn't register anything new

Comment: Have you tried echoing the $username variable to see if it is set? Maybe something is wrong there. also do a print_r on the $result and $row to see what it says

Comment: im really sorry very new to php, the $username show correctly but the if statement doesn't seem to work....

Comment: i change it to this.. but nothing :(


if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
    $result = mysql_query($con,"INSERT INTO user(fname, lname, username, email, password, Role)
    values('$fname', '$lname', '$username', '$email', '$password', '$Role')");
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Role FROM user where 
 username='$username'");
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 $data = $row[0];
    echo $data;

Comment: umm... my server crashed O_o i'll probably try it tomorrow
since my server takes forever to boot up >_<

Comment: Yeah sorry, had a bug in there, fixing it up. New code will be up in a couple of minutes, so you should be good to go, once you are back tomorrow. I'm testing it this time ;) Sorry for that.

Comment: So this time the code is tested and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks i tried it on my mobile it works.. later i'll do it with my server :3

Comment: It works!!! wait how do you get current date to be place into my sql? i just realize it now O_o

Comment: i just did it like this but it empty =>>> $userStmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, username, email, password, Role, date_created) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :username, :email, :password, :Role, now())");